# Specifying future transactions in an Ethereum Contract

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

Bitcoin has an nLockTime parameter that can be associated with a transaction to specify the minimal time that must pass before the transaction can be added to a block. Is it possible to do something similar within an Ethereum contract?

Comment: This may get more attention on the [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or the [Ethereum Stack Exchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/). :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to send a transaction and a time when the transaction can be executed to a smart contract. The contract stores the transaction for later use.

After the given time elapsed and the transaction is ready to be executed, you have following options:

1. Send an another transaction to the smart contract asking the first transaction to be executed.
2. Integrate the smart contract with the Alarm Clock solution (http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com). That will allow stored transactions to be executed automatically.